# PHP / MySQL - MySQL query to sort results per specific column

Tags: php, mysql

I'm trying to do a query and sort my search results order by a specific column.

**Selecting the search results :**

```
$query = "SELECT * 
          FROM `orders` 
          WHERE CONCAT(`KeyAccount`, `BatchNumber`, `Product`, `Quantity`, `PO`, `DateRequested`, `DateDelivered`, `Status`, `Serial`, `Voucher`, `DateExpiry`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
$search_result = filterTable($query);
```

**Full search results source code :**

```
<?php

if(isset($_GET['search']))
{
    $valueToSearch = $_GET['valueToSearch'];
    // search in all table columns
    // using concat mysql function
    $query = "SELECT * 
              FROM `orders` 
              WHERE CONCAT(`KeyAccount`, `BatchNumber`, `Product`, `Quantity`, `PO`, `DateRequested`, `DateDelivered`, `Status`, `Serial`, `Voucher`, `DateExpiry`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%'";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);  
}
else {
    $query = "SELECT * FROM `orders`";
    $search_result = filterTable($query);
}

// function to connect and execute the query
function filterTable($query)
{
    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "test");
    $filter_Result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);
    return $filter_Result;
}

?>
```

***I'm thinking of using `ORDER BY`, or maybe using a join?***

Not familliar though, any help is appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You must add at the end of the query:

```
order by 1 asc;
```

1 is the column number or you can write the column name

```
order by Product asc;
```

or you can do multiple sort

```
order by Product asc, KeyAccount desc;
```

Check [this](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_orderby.asp)

Answer (score 0):

You can make use of `order by` something like this

This query returns last 10 records ordered by batch number in descending order .

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM `orders` WHERE CONCAT(`KeyAccount`, `BatchNumber`, 
  `Product`, `Quantity`, `PO`, `DateRequested`, `DateDelivered`, 
  `Status`, `Serial`, `Voucher`, `DateExpiry`) LIKE '%".$valueToSearch."%' order by `BatchNumber` desc limit 10";
```

Comment: Very simple, yet helpful for sure! more to learn for me, Thank you!!